# "for loop" with a changing variable name in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a function as shown here. It takes as an argument, an array with 8 values.

It supposed to go through textbox2 -> check for string inside it, if so goto textbox3 and write the first value of the array, and the general rule if textbox$i isn't empty, print inside textbox$i+1 the value of $passarray[$counter] and add $counter + 1.

The function will halt when it reaches an empty textbox.

I have a few problems here, first I need to find a way to make sure the inside of the if statement that the word $textbox is changing, $textbox2, $textbox4, $textbox6 and so on.

As it is written here it doesn't do the job

```
Function FillBoxes ($passarray) {
 $counter =0
  For ($i=2; $i -lt 17; $i=$i+2){
          if ($textbox$i.textlength -gt 0) {
                $TextBox$i+1.text =  $passarray[$counter]
                $counter++}
                }


 }

how can i do it correcrtly?
```

Comment: Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62130576/9898643) on your other question about the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the get-variable cmdlet will resolve your issue.

```
$i = 2;

$testEcho_2 = 'Hello'

Get-Variable -Name ('testEcho_' + $i) -ValueOnly

Write-Host $(Get-Variable -Name ('testEcho_' + $i) -ValueOnly)

$tmp = ('testEcho_' + $i)

New-Variable -Name "testEcho_$i" -Value 'After Mod' -Force

Write-Host $(Get-Variable -Name ('testEcho_' + $i) -ValueOnly)
```

see also: [Evaluate a variable within a variable in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340525/evaluate-a-variable-within-a-variable-in-powershell)

Comment: Hi i can get the variable name but how can i set it? this is a textbox , can i do something like: get-variable -name textbox$i | $_.text "blabla"