# Using another variable to store context inside a different variable

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to add value inside a textbox.text variable only I don't want to use another variable for that issue:

```
$temp = '$textbox'

$textbox.text = "this will store this string exactly as I want"

# I want to use temp for that issue but this code of course won't work:

$temp.text = "this will not work"
```

How can I use this `$temp` variable to call the `$textbox` variable?

EDIT:

I have a gui with 8 Textboxes, 2 on each row.
the left row are named textbox2 textbox4 textbox6 and so on
the right row are named textbox3 textbox5 textbox7 and so on.
the idea is this: 
i have an array with 8 items. 
if i have text inside a textbox to the left, i put an array item inside the corresponsing textbox to the right. E.g:

```
if (textbox2.textlength -gt 0) #meaning its not empty textbox
 {textbox3.text = $array[0]} #corresponding textbox to the right will get value from array
```

so i have to check textbox2,4,6,8 and so on, and each time i see a value i need to take the next array item and put it inside the right textbox 
im gonna add a picture:
[image]

i hope its clear.
i want to create a loop for this issue but i cannot do something like:

```
for ($i=2; $i -lt 17; $i=$i+2){
    if (textbox$i.textlength -gt 0 ) #of cours this wont work..
```

MORE EDIT:
this is the code that i want to put inside a loop:

```
 Function FillBoxes ($passarray) {

     if ($textbox2.textlength -gt 0) {
      $textbox3.text = $passarray[0]}

      if ($textbox4.textlength -gt 0) {
      $textbox5.text = $passarray[1]}

     if ($textbox6.textlength -gt 0) {
      $textbox7.text = $passarray[2]}

     if ($textbox8.textlength -gt 0) {
      $textbox9.text = $passarray[3]}

     if ($textbox10.textlength -gt 0) {
      $textbox11.text = $passarray[4]}

     if ($textbox12.textlength -gt 0) {
      $textbox13.text = $passarray[5]}

     if ($textbox14.textlength -gt 0) {
      $textbox15.text = $passarray[6]}

     if ($textbox16.textlength -gt 0) {
      $textbox17.text = $passarray[7]}
     }
```

Comment: Is `$textbox` a class which has the text property?

Comment: i confess that i cannot figure out what you are talking about. perhaps if you show what you want it would be a bit more understandable ...

Comment: Did you personally define the `.text` class? I'm sorry I can't understand your code.

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to make a array of textboxes and then if any textbox is not empty then do something

Comment: the code should check service1 textbox, if its not empty it should go to textbox to the right and put info there. it should loop through all the textboxes, the info that the code should put in in there is stored inside an array. meaning $array[0] will goto the first textbox (the top right one) $array[1] will go to the second one (the second on the right) and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can make it easier by using the `.Name` property when you create the TextBoxes:

```
for ($i = 2; $i -lt 17; $i++) {
    $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBox.Name = "TextBox$i"
    # add the rest of the textbox properties and add to the forms Controls array
    $form.Controls.Add($textBox) 
}
```

Then, in your `FillBoxes` function you can select the boxes by their name

```
for ($i = 2; $i -lt 17; $i += 2) {
    $tb = $form.Controls.Item("TextBox$i")
    if (!([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($tb.Text))) {
        $form.Controls.Item("TextBox$($i + 1)").Text = $passarray[$i - 2]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like what Lee_Dailey says, I am really taken aback by what you are saying here.

Without doing the logic check, is the looping effort you are after?

```
[array]$passarray = 1..17

for ($i=2; $i -lt 17; $i=$i+2){
    switch ($i) 
        { 
            2  
            {
                "Textbox_text$i"
                "Value to assign to text box is: $($passarray[0])"
            } 
            4  
                        {
                "Textbox_text$i"
                 "Value to assign to text box is: $($passarray[1])"
            } 
            6  
            {
                "Textbox_text$i"
                "Value to assign to text box is: $($passarray[2])"
            } 
            8  
            {
                "Textbox_text$i"
                "Value to assign to text box is: $($passarray[3])"
            } 
            10 
            {
                "Textbox_text$i"
                "Value to assign to text box is: $($passarray[4])"
            } 
            12 
            {
                "Textbox_text$i"
                "Value to assign to text box is: $($passarray[5])"
            } 
            14 
            {
                "Textbox_text$i"
                 "Value to assign to text box is: $($passarray[6])"
            } 
            16 
            {
                "Textbox_text$i"
                "Value to assign to text box is: $($passarray[7])"
            } 
            default {$PSItem | Out-Null}
        }
}

# Results

Textbox_text2
Value to assign to text box is: 1
Textbox_text4
Value to assign to text box is: 2
Textbox_text6
Value to assign to text box is: 3
Textbox_text8
Value to assign to text box is: 4
Textbox_text10
Value to assign to text box is: 5
Textbox_text12
Value to assign to text box is: 6
Textbox_text14
Value to assign to text box is: 7
Textbox_text16
Value to assign to text box is: 8
```

Of course, You can easily extend that logic in the switch to whatever you choose.